# How to move the starting of a character animations in blender?

Tags: animation

I have a character animation in fbx for which the starting point is wrong.
The starting point is too much in the front, so when I use it in runtime, my is quickly teleporting or slidding a few meters in the front before starting the animation.

I would like to move the starting point of the animation at the center of scene.

I think I can do that by adding a key location at each frames, but given the number of frames it would nearly impossible to achieve this properly, so is there a way to just  set the starting point and let blender calculate the shift for all subsequent frames

https://we.tl/t-F1apnmBis5

Comment: depends on your animation. so pls provide blend file or watch tutorials about rigging.

Comment: Here is the blend file. https://we.tl/t-F1apnmBis5

Comment: Hi Bamb, i understand that being lazy is a good thing (i am too), but...in your situation - and i assume you want help for free from us in our spare time - i would provide as much help for those who wanna help, to make their life easier so that they can help me quicker. So i asked for a blend file, you provided a fbx file. Of course i can import that on my own - but it is just a rig. I cannot even "see" the character. So sorry - but i don't wanna help you under that circumstances. I hope you understand that.

Comment: And one more thing: you should provide blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/, because if you delete your file in "your" cloud service, it becomes useless

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to offset the location of your armature:

- Parent it to an empty and move the empty wherever you want.
- Select the root bone (or all the bones if there are no root bone), go in the *Graph Editor*, select the location track of this bone, move the curve on the Y axis of the *Graph Editor* window (upwards).

Comment: Thanks Moonboots. I'll try that